# Working multiple consoles in python

Tags: python

I know that it is an easy question but I can't do this. I have to do two things. One of them is a management program that will manage the program, e.g stop, pause, resume. The other thing will only show logs. So I need 2 consoles.

1. How can I open two consoles?
2. How to pass a log from management console to logging console. Example code is below:

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while True:
            initialmyProgram()
            print('Please press \'1\' key to stop program..\n')
            print('Please press \'5\' key to resume program..\n')
            print('Please press \'0\' key to exit program..\n')
            isStart = raw_input('Please press a key that must be in above list..')
            if isStart == 1:
                parse.__is__process__ = False
            elif isStart == 5:
                parse.__is__process__ = True
            elif isStart == 0 :
                exit_program()
            else:
                continue
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.info('log..') #this log will write other console..
```

Comment: No, i have two module.

Comment: I am not sure if this is even possible. You want to start a program from the terminal and you want it to open an extra terminal for you?

Comment: yes,exactly i want you say.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need two python consoles to accomplish this.

If you're using linux or a mac, open up a python console and a second terminal.

Then type this command in the second terminal:

```
tail -f path_to/filename_of_logfile
```

This will refresh the log file automatically.

An alternative solution if you absolutely cannot use files, is to use sockets to have to python programs communicate. Here's a link to get you started:

[Python Sockets](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)

Comment: I don't want to write log in a file. I only will show log in console. And i am on windows.

Comment: Edited the answer to include how to do this without files.

Comment: I thought it is easy problem :)

Comment: Files are a fairly straightforward solution to this. There are a thousand other ways to skin this problem but files are the easiest way to go about doing it in my opinion.